# Accessing API using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp, geturl

I have tried accessing url by the below method.The url consists of JSON data which needs to be parsed but got a **Cross-Origin Request Blocked:** error.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'http://...',
async:true,
dataType : 'json',
crossDomain:true,
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
alert(data);
}
```

});

Then I tried to add **JSONP** to **dataType** for resolving cross origin request then got the following error - **SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'**

The code snippet is given below -

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://....',
dataType: 'JSONP',
jsonpCallback: 'callback',
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
})
```

The json to be accessed from url is of the form -

```
{"data":[{"name":"abc","age":24},{"name":"xyz","age":22}]}
```

I am a beginner.Please provide a solution regarding how to access the data in the url using jquery or javascript without the cross domain error and without using PHP.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that other domain is returning the json in the form of wrapped callback function?

Comment: No, It is exactly the same as I provided the json structure above.

Comment: Then it won't work. when using JSONP jquery will attach random callback function in the requesting url and the response should be wrapped in the callback function.

Comment: Can this be achieved with json only?